Use of "had to" after could/would have
Can a construction be like "I would have had to study, if I had an exam"
The presence of "had to" post "would have" is a bit confusing as my knowledge is limited to knowing that "would have had" is used to indicate possession/experience that were probable in the past. T

If you mean that you didn't study because you didn't have an exam, it would be "I would have had to study if I had had an exam".

could have had to, should have had to, might have had to do something.

OP's example text is fine. Start with the bare statement...

1: I studied to pass the exam

...add "final result" and "forced, obligation" elements...

2: To get the job I had to study to pass the exam
(It was necessary to study to pass the exam and get the job)

...add a conditional element...

3: To get the job I would have had to study to pass the exam
(But because I didn't study, I didn't pass the exam and didn't get the job)

There's no real connection between have to (obligation) and auxiliary have used in Perfect, Past, and Conditional verb forms. They're often not even pronounced the same.
In to have to [do something] (be obliged to do it), the word have is often enunciated as haff. Correspondingly, in the Past Tense version I had to [do it], had is often enunciated as hat.


I would have had to study ...

Edit
The OP’s example is fine, as FF explained in his answer.
My examples in my earlier answer are of different constructions, for different usage.

To get here by breakfast time, I would have had to start yesterday.

Usually in speech, "...I would have HAT to start yesterday".

@FumbleFingers - Hat? Like on your head? Really? Are you sure? Is the sun over the yard-arm where you are?  By the way, I want an Oppenheimer hat, and I am so tired of people, especially hat retailers, thinking it's a 'fedora'. It's NOT.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers and Michael.  Agreed that the OP’s example is fine.

@MichaelHarvey: See Do you pronounce  as /ˈhæftuː/o /ˈhæftə/?. In which cases do you replace the v with the f in ? where the first comment says This is common to most native English accents.  Also When is "have to" pronounced /ˈhæf tə/? Linguistics Prof John Lawler always wrote hafta, not havta, as I recall, so it's AmE as well as BrE.

@FumbleFingers - oh, right! No, it's vee all the way here! And had, not hat.
